# Look up list of values on different worksheets and return both column and row header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

[image]I am trying to look up a list of values in multiple worksheets of a workbook and return both the column header and row header in the cells next to my search value.
I found a code that works perfect for all values in my first column of data (ColB) in the active worksheet. If I add values to my list that are located in another column or another worksheet I get a circular reference error and it places a 0 in my function cells.
I have put my list of values to look up in column 1 under my last row of data and put both functions in the columns next to them.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

My workbook consists of a growing amount of worksheets in the same format.
Every worksheet has Column headers in Row 1 and row haeaders in Column 1, 81 rows and 40 columns filled with data. The list of values to be looked up can be up to 1000 or more.

```
    Function MyROW(MyVAL)
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    FFIND = False
    For J = .Column + 1 To .Column + .Columns.Count
        For I = .Row + 1 To .Row + .Rows.Count
            If (Cells(I, J) = MyVAL) Then
                FFIND = True
                GoTo MyEND
            End If
        Next I
    Next J
    MyEND:
    If (FFIND) Then MyROW = Cells(I, .Column)
End With
```

End Function

```
    Function MyCOLUMN(MyVAL)
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    FFIND = False
    For J = .Column + 1 To .Column + .Columns.Count
        For I = .Row + 1 To .Row + .Rows.Count
            If (Cells(I, J) = MyVAL) Then
                FFIND = True
                GoTo MyEND
            End If
        Next I
    Next J
    MyEND:
    If (FFIND) Then MyCOLUMN = Cells(.Row, J)
End With
```

End Function

[image]

In cell B84 I placed this function: =MyCOLUMN(A84) and pulled it down to the cells beneath it. In cell C84 I did the same with function: =MyROW(A84). The functions both work well if I put a value in A84 that can be found in A2-A82, but not if I put a value in a84 that can be found in B2-AO82.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post & share the formula which are working & not working,  you are using with MyColumn & MyRow function !

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I added a comment under the picture of the table. Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Your Screen shot has only 38 rows,,, please check & correct it !

Comment: Rajesh, I added a screenshot of my entire table, but I don't think it will help you much.  For the test fase I just filled two colums in stead of all 40.

Comment: You may find [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-on-multiple-columns) to be useful

Comment: Thank you for your reply cybernetic. I will look into that a bit more. Do you know a way to alter that to return the row and column headers too?

Comment: @Caroline, I've tried both of your VBA functions,, but sometimes even failed to return correct values from the current sheet !! Not working for another sheet because,, code has ACTIVE Sheet used for the job!!

Comment: Thanks Rajesh S. Found out it only returns the right value if I place my function in the same column as where the look up value is located. Will try next week to see if I can use something else than Active sheet or if I will try a completely different code.